# Custom Windows Task Bar

Tags: windows

For security reasons, I have changed the Windows shell to a custom application I wrote.  I have created a bar at the bottom of the screen similar to the Task Bar that I currently call a status bar since it doesn't hold icons to select tasks.  My main question is this:

**Can I make this status bar take up its screen space such that other applications will not render themselves under it?**  Note that I've already set it to be Always on Top, which works great, except that other windows show up under it.

For example, if the screen is 1680x1050, can I make this status bar take up the bottom 50 pixel rows of the screen, but have Windows then tell applications that the screen is 1680x1000 (which is what I assume happens when using the actual Windows Task Bar)?

A related question:

- Can I alternately somehow extend the actual Windows Task Bar such that I get all Windows Task Bar functionality, but control exactly how it behaves?  Maybe via a Task Bar subclass?

Answer (score 1):

Use [SHAppBarMessage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762108(v=vs.85).aspx). See example in [article](https://www.microsoft.com/msj/archive/s274.aspx). To related questions - no public API.

Comment: This appears to work great when the default Windows shell (explorer.exe) is running, but doesn't appear to have any effect when the shell is overridden.  It must be a function of explorer.exe itself.  This answer was still very useful.